# MS Access VBA Wildcard works in one version not in the other

Tags: vba, ms-access

I an access front end in which users are allowed to pull reports to see what is going on with hardware.

I have the following code segments, one is in the older database, which is being replaced and refactored:

Note that the issue here is that the wildcard is reading in the old database such that : "Device :*" does a search for any object with the starting category of "Device :" and then allows a search even without specifying something to search the report for. This is the desired outcome. The new code, which was copy/pasted excepting for the change in the name of the combobox and the textbox, doesn't do this. It isn't reading the * as a wildcard at all, I have tried moving it outside the "" with chr(34) chr(42) chr(34) etc.
Old functioning code:

```
If IsNull(Me.cmb_FieldName) Then
    MsgBox "Select a field from the list to search", , "Search Object Error"
    Exit Sub
ElseIf IsNull(Me.txt_Search) And Me.cmb_FieldName <> "Active" And Me.cmb_FieldName <> "Device :*" Then
    MsgBox "And what are you searching for?", , "Search Object Error"
    Exit Sub
ElseIf Me.cmb_FieldName = "Active" And Me.txt_Search <> "Yes" And Me.txt_Search <> "No" And Me.txt_Search <> Null Then
    MsgBox "Valid entries for active device search are Yes or No" & vbCrLf & "Defaults to Yes.", _
    , "Active Search Object Error"
End If
```

New malfunctioning code:

```
If IsNull(Me.cmb_SearchField) Then
    MsgBox "Select a field from the list to search", , "Search Object Error"
    Exit Sub
ElseIf IsNull(Me.txt_SearchText) And Me.cmb_SearchField <> "Active" And Me.cmb_SearchField <> "Device :*" Then
    MsgBox "And what are you searching for?", , "Search Object Error"
    Exit Sub
ElseIf Me.cmb_SearchField = "Active" And Me.txt_SearchText <> "Yes" And Me.txt_SearchText <> "No" And Me.txt_SearchText <> Null Then
    MsgBox "Valid entries for active device search are Yes or No" & vbCrLf & "Defaults to Yes.", _
    , "Active Search Object Error"
End If
```

What should happen, is it should search for "Active" or a specific device type and pull up that relevant report. This works in the old front end, but in the new front end, it simply doesn't accept the condition, and moves into that first elseif even when those particular AND conditions are met.

The original code, which to my eye looks identical seems to work properly.
All the same references in the same order exist. And the original code was simply copy-pasted to the new front end. All Reports/Queries/Tables were brought in (Tables by link to Backend).

While the control names have changed, they are essentially the same controls. cmb_FieldName is 1:1 with cmb_SearchField and txt_Search is an unbound textbox just as is txt_SearchText

cmb_FieldName & Cmb_SearchField have the following information in them (Pulled directly from the properties line) "

> "AccountInfo";"Aztek";"Bios";"DateAssigned";"Department";"DeviceNum";"Device : Cell";"Device : Laptops";"Device : PC";"Device : Printers";"Device : Tablets";"Device : ThinClients";"Device : Others";"IP";"Location";"MAC";"Mfg";"Model";"NetworkName";"SerialNum";"TeamviewerID";"PhoneNum";"User";"WTTag";"Audit Log Search";"IT Staff"

and

> "AccountInfo";"Aztek";"Bios";"DateAssigned";"Department";"DeviceNum";"Device : Cell";"Device : Laptops";"Device : PC";"Device : Printers";"Device : Tablets";"Device : ThinClients";"Device : Others";"IP";"Location";"MAC";"Mfg";"Model";"NetworkName";"SerialNum";"TeamviewerID";"PhoneNum";"User";"WTTag";"Audit Log Search";"IT Staff"

Respectively. The empty textbox is used when searching for something specific, in this case we're only interested in searching for the generic "Device : Cell" etc. which will pull up a full report on all Cellphones for example.

I have narrowed down the issue to this line:

```
ElseIf IsNull(Me.txt_SearchText) And Me.cmb_SearchField <> "Device :*" Then
```

Which should evaluate as false understanding the * as a wildcard, which works in the older version of the database. But in the newer one, "Device :*" seems to be interpreting literally, and I have no idea why.

At this point I even tried using SQLserver compatibility wildcards (%) but same exact results.

Comment: The controls referenced in your conditions are not the same. Example: Old: `If IsNull(Me.cmb_FieldName) Then` New: `If IsNull(Me.cmb_SearchField) Then` - we can't help you debug this because we don't know what is in these controls, whether they are the same controls with new names, or new controls, or the old controls but now used differently than before ... you will have to provide more details.

Comment: @topsail I added in more details into the question itself, is that the type of information needed?

Comment: Set a break-point and see which values are in these controls. See how to [debug your code](https://www.google.com/search?q=debugging+VBA+Code+-%22Visual+Studio%22)

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Already did that, the only difference I can find, and I can't figure out WHY it's different is in the older DB the textbox is empty and in the new one it's Null.

Comment: For wildcards you need `Like`. `And Not (Me.cmb_SearchField Like "Device :*")`

Comment: I tend to use the `Nz` method when dealing with null values (e.g. `If Nz(Me.cmb_SearchField) = "" Then`. It captures null and empty values in one hit by returning a zero-length string.

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare with *Null*. Use `IsNull`:

```
ElseIf Me.cmb_SearchField = "Active" And Me.txt_SearchText <> "Yes" And Me.txt_SearchText <> "No" And Not IsNull(Me.txt_SearchText) Then
```

Comment: Oddly, that line works fine, it's the ElseIf statement above it that is breaking.

Comment: ? It can't "break" anything.

Comment: Let's instead say it is introducing undesired features.